# So what exactly are perverse sheaves anyway?

Tags: ct.category-theory, derived-categories, perverse-sheaves

Is there a way to define perverse sheaves categorically/geometrically? Definitions like the following from lectures by Sophie Morel:

> The category of perverse sheaves on $X$ is $\mathrm{Perv}(X,F):=D^{\leq 0} \cap D^{\geq 0}$. We write $^p\mathrm{H}^k \colon D_c^b(X,F) \to \mathrm{Perv}(X,F)$ for the cohomology functors given by the $\mathrm{t}$-structure.

are well and good, but to me, it feels like they come with too many "luggages", and therefore make me feel like I don't have as good of an intuition of derived categories as I should.

Comment: Although this question's got upvotes already, so obviously some folks like it (and I can see the appeal!), it seems to me that observing that a definition carries 'luggage' doesn't really constitute a well defined question.  I can see that the visible geometry is squeezed out of the definition, but what's not categorical about it?

Comment: @LSpice I wasn't sure about the terminology (hence the slash). Do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: I don't—actually, although I am sympathetic to the urge to ask this question, I think that it should be more precisely formed (so as, ideally, to have a well defined answer, and probably a single one) before asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An $\infty$-categorical perspective is given here https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03913 and a triangulated expansion of those ideas is here https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.00883

More or less, perverse sheaves are the heart of a certain $t$-structure that you build "gluing along a perversity datum".

Answer (score 16):

If you're looking for a more geometric interpretation of perverse sheaves, you might be interested in MacPherson's 1990 lecture notes "Intersection Homology and Perverse Sheaves." As far as I know, I don't think these were ever officially published, but you can find them on my web site at:
http://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/notes/ih.pdf

Answer (score 11):

After some searching I've found the notes *[An illustrated guide to perverse sheaves](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/geordie/perverse_course/lectures.pdf)*, by Geordie Williamson, which is a beautifully illustrated (and sort of topologically oriented) introduction to perverse sheaves.